# (List<int[]> list - параметр метода , как это сделать из массива int?

Tags: java

Объясните пожалуйста, как это выглядит в коде. Т.е. есть массивы типа int и как их загнать в метод:

```
public List<Integer> convert (List<int[]> list) {

}
```

**Описание:** этом методе вы должны пройтись по всем элементам всех массивов в списке `list` и добавить их в один общий лист `Integer`. Массивы в списке list могут быть разного размера. Например:

```
list.add(new int[]{1, 2});
list.add(new int[]{3, 4, 5, 6});
List<Integer> result = convertList.convert(list);
```

`List<Integer> result` будет содержать элементы: `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`.

Не понимаю, как их преобразовать в тип  `List<int[]> list`.

Comment: Расскажите что должен делать метод. Приведите пример входного и выходного списка.

Comment: В этом методе вы должны пройтись по всем элементам всех массивов в списке list и добавить их в один общий лист Integer.

Массивы в списке list могут быть разного размера.

Например:
list.add(new int[]{1, 2})
list.add(new int[]{3, 4, 5, 6})
List<Integer> result = convertList.convert(list)

List<Integer> result будет содержать элементы: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

Comment: Дженерики в java не могут быть примитивного типа. Можно передавать `List<Integer[]>`, а в методе создать результирующий список и добавлять в него `Arrays.asList(<your_array>)`.

Comment: @StasDorozhko нельзя использовать в качестве дженерика примитив (List<int>), а массив из примитивов (List<int[]>) - можно

Comment: Не совсем ясно о чем вопрос: нужно написать метод или вызвать его? Лучше сконцентрироваться на чем-то одном.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример с использованием Stream API:

```
public List<Integer> convert(List<int[]> list) {
    return list.stream().flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Пример "по старинке":

```
public static List<Integer> convert(List<int[]> list) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int[] ints: list) {
        for (int i: ints) {
            result.add(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Вызов:

```
List<Integer> result = convert(asList(new int[]{1, 2}, new int[]{3, 4, 5, 6}));
System.out.println(result);
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: спасибо . а как при вызове метода туда передать параметр т.е как упаковать передаваемое значение ?

Comment: @Terasan не понял ваш вопрос. добавил пример вызова в ответ, если вы имели ввиду это.

Comment: да именно это имел ввиду . В первый раз с этим столкнулся . Теперь понял как. Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста. [Не благодарите автора ответа в комментариях - Вы можете отметить ответ правильным, если он лучше всего решает именно вашу задачу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)